# How to change Label color on Entry GotFocus from CollectionView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to bind the state of FontColor of Label in Xamarin so that it highlights the Label when Entry(textbox) gets focus?

```
<CollectionView x:Name="documentsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentsList}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                           ItemSpacing="0" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="0,10,0,0"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"  FontSize="Body"/>
                            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                               IsPassword="False"
                               Keyboard="Numeric"
                               Placeholder="{Binding Count}"
                               Text="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                               Unfocused="{Binding OnTextboxLostFocus}"
                               Focused="{Binding OnTextboxGotFocus}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

I need to highlight the element which is going to be changed when the user enters data to the Entry(textbox), and because the space between elements in CollectionView should be less so that I can show as much data per scroll as possible it might confuse the user which element exactly he is changing. I thought about passing a label as a parameter to the Events but could not find out how to bind the label.

Comment: bind IsFocused to a bool on your VM.  Bind the Label's TextColor to the same bool using a ValueConverter

Comment: Won't all of the labels be bounded to the same bool value and on its change all of them will be changed? I mean, what I need is that to change the color of the label which belongs to the row on which Entry got focused

Comment: no, each element in your datasource should have an IsFocused property, not the entire VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `textColor` of label to a property in model and update that `textColor` when the `entry focused/unfocused`.

Here is an example I use:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new DncMvvmPageModel();
    }
}

public class DncMvvmPageModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Document> DocumentsList { get; set; }
    public Command OnTextboxLostFocus { get; }
    public Command OnTextboxGotFocus { get; }

    public DncMvvmPageModel()
    {
        OnTextboxLostFocus = new Command(OnTextboxLostFocusMethod);
        OnTextboxGotFocus = new Command(OnTextboxGotFocusMethod);

        DocumentsList = new ObservableCollection<Document>();

        DocumentsList.Add(new Document() {TextColor = Color.Gray });
        DocumentsList.Add(new Document() { TextColor = Color.Gray });
        DocumentsList.Add(new Document() { TextColor = Color.Gray });
        DocumentsList.Add(new Document() { TextColor = Color.Gray });
    }

    public void OnTextboxLostFocusMethod(object sender) {
        FocusEventArgs args = sender as FocusEventArgs;
        Entry entry = args.VisualElement as Entry;
        Document docu = entry.BindingContext as Document;

        docu.TextColor = Color.Red;
    }

    public void OnTextboxGotFocusMethod(object sender)
    {
        FocusEventArgs args = sender as FocusEventArgs;
        Entry entry = args.VisualElement as Entry;
        Document docu = entry.BindingContext as Document;

        docu.TextColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}

public class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    Color textColor;

    public Color TextColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (textColor != value)
            {
                textColor = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextColor"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return textColor;
        }
    }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="documentsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentsList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                       ItemSpacing="0" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="0,10,0,0"
                           Text="Name"  FontSize="Body" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"/>
                <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                           IsPassword="False"
                           Keyboard="Numeric"
                           Placeholder="placeholder"
                           Text="Count">

                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Focused"
                                      Command="{Binding BindingContext.OnTextboxGotFocus, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" />
                        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused"
                                      Command="{Binding BindingContext.OnTextboxLostFocus, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>

                </Entry>
                  
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Result:

[image]

Feel free to ask me any question if you have:).